SSIS MSOLEDBSQL: ConnectRetryCount, ConnectRetryInterval
Using SSISDB on server A, we have a parent package that loops through a configuration table and executes several hundred stored procedures on server B. Occasionally one of the processes fails with
Failed to acquire connection "". Connection may not be configured correctly, or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
This is typically in the middle of the execution, so a connection has been made in previous steps. We are currently using an OLEDB Connection (Native Client) for these connections. I have proposed switching the connections to MSOLEDBSQL to use the Connection Resiliency features (Connect Retry Count, Connect Retry Interval). When testing locally, I disconnect from our VPN and I can see the package (under the Progress tab) attempting to reconnect at the intervals specified in the Connection Manager>Properties>ConnectRetryCount & ConnectRetryInterval (which override the ConnectionString values of Connect Retry Count=xxx; Connect Retry Interval=xxx;).
When deploying to the SSISDB and trying to set these values in the SSISDB under Configure... for the Project Connection Managers:
ConnectRetryInterval
ConnectRetryCount
I receive the following error:

Failed to configure a connection property that has the following path:
Message: \Packages.Connections...Properties[ConnectRetryInterval].
Element "ConnectRetryInterval" does not exist in collection
"Properties". Message Source Name: Transact-SQL stored procedure

Has anyone been able to get these settings to work?
Tried setting values in Environment variables. Tried setting values in Connection String.
